# Limit groups in Sharepoint 2010 list view

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How do you limit groups displayed on a Sharepoint 2010 list view with CAML?

```
<Query>
  <GroupBy Collapse="FALSE">
    <FieldRef Name="MyField" Ascending="FALSE" />
  </GroupBy>
  <OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Name="MyField" />
  </OrderBy>
</Query>
```

I want to display only first 3 groups. Is it possible to do that with CAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I exported a view with sharepoint designer and it has

```
<Query>
  <GroupBy Collapse="FALSE" GroupLimit="3">
    <FieldRef Name="MyField" Ascending="FALSE" />
  </GroupBy>
</Query>
```

But it isnt in the schema

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415157.aspx

Comment: I itentionally removed 'GroupLimit="3"' part out, because it doesn't make any difference. It doesn't limit number of groups nor number of items in a group...

Comment: I will try to clear browser cache and redeploy/reactivate my feature. I'll mark it as answered if it works.

Comment: GroupLimit is used in SPViews, but as for SPQuery, no it wont. i dont think there is any way

Answer (score 0):

if you want to limit rows returned by caml query use this :

```
SPQuery qry = new SPQuery();

qry.RowLimit = 3;

string camlquery = " ";

qry.Query = camlquery;
```